# How to tell the compiler that a value can"t be undefined in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

let's say I have this component that Wrap other component in react.

```
interface LoadWrapperProps {
  defined?: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
}

export const LoadWrapper = ({loading, children }: LoadWrapperProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      {defined ? (
        <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center">
          <div className={className}>
            <Spinner  />
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        { children }
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Now I would like to use this like this

```
const { data } = useMyQuery<X>(); // data is type X | undefined

<LoadWrapper defined={data}>
   <AnotherComponent data={data} /> // here data is type X | undefined but I would like only X since the check has been done on the wrapper.
</LoadWrapper>
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a nice way while keeping the current structure the same - but a simple tweak could do it. Note that the LoadWrapper does nothing but render the children after loading, and does nothing but render other elements (that don't use the children) otherwise. So, it's not so much a *wrapper*, so much as a conditional element. Consider moving the condition outside, and then TypeScript will be able to understand when `data` is or isn't defined.

```
export const LoadWrapper = () => (
  <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center">
    <div className={className}>
      <Spinner />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

```
const { data } = useMyQuery<X>();

return data
  ? <AnotherComponent data={data} />
  : <LoadWrapper />;
```

Or, if it's surrounded by other JSX, you could do something like

```
<div>{
  data
    ? <AnotherComponent data={data} />
    : <LoadWrapper />
}</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I do agree in this simple exemple, but it  is a bit simplified here. In the app currently, it is kind of a component that render child if there is no loading, no error, and handle some logic about errors. It also remove the visual complecity of a lot of ternary to show or not different part of of the page based on queries. It doen"t touch directly the data, but it does kind of certify that nothing is loading and nothing has error.

Answer (score 0):

Although the previous response is a good one and, in my opinion, has a better structure, if you want to stay with de same component structure, it may work with a type cast over `data` variable, like:

```js
<LoadWrapper defined={data}>
   <AnotherComponent data={data as X} /> // or "data as unknown as X"
</LoadWrapper>
```

Comment: `as` and `!` need to be added to each time data is used, and it s something that eslint would not like ^^